# Filter , Sort and Find element in a ArrayList using Java8

Tags: java, sorting, filter

I have an List of GUIDs, from which I need to select the latest Active GUID. I wrote the code using traditional Java. I am trying to write with Java 8. Any suggestions ?

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class Guid {
    
    private String guid ;

    private String active;

    private Date created ;
    }

  public class StreamFilterSortMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<Guid> guids = new ArrayList<>();
    guids.add(new Guid("guid1","YES",new Date()));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    guids.add(new Guid("guid2","NO",new Date()));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    guids.add(new Guid("guid3","YES",new Date()));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    guids.add(new Guid("guid4","YES",new Date()));


    //Traditional Java
    Guid pGuid = filterAndThenSortUsingTraditonalJava(guids);
    System.out.println("Guid="+pGuid);

}

private static Guid filterAndThenSortUsingTraditonalJava(List<Guid> guids) {
    Guid processedGuid = null;

    //Use Iterator or Create New ArrayList
    List<Guid> filteredGuids = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Guid guid: guids) {

        if(guid.getActive().equals("YES")){
            filteredGuids.add(guid);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(filteredGuids, new Comparator<Guid>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Guid o1, Guid o2) {
            return o2.getCreated().compareTo(o1.getCreated());
        }
    });

    processedGuid = filteredGuids.get(0);

    return processedGuid;

   }


   }
```

How to rewrite the method using filterAndThenSortUsingTraditonalJava() using Java8 . I am pretty new to Java8. Really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this satisfies your requirement

```
   private static Guid filterAndThenSort(List<Guid> guids) {

   return guids
            .stream() //we can use stream or parallelstream
            .filter( guid ->  guid.getActive().equals("YES") ) // filters guid if active euals YES
            .sorted((guid1, guid2) -> guid2.getCreated().compareTo(guid1.getCreated())) // sorting using timestamp descending
            .findFirst() // findfirst element
            .orElse(null); //if element not found return null

}
```

Comment: This is what exactly I was trying to do. Thank you @Naga